# How does post-increment work on an assignment(with the same variable)?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, post-increment

I have this code...

```
for(int i=0; i<10 ; ) {
    i = i++;
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World...
```

The loop will repeat infinitely, because `i`  remains `0` after every iteration of the loop.

I thought this expression `i = i++;` was redundant... like this one `i=(i=i+1);`, but it remains `0` so how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

`i = i++;` is a tricky construct, what it really does is something like the following:

```
int iOld = i;
i = i + 1;
i = iOld;
```

First, the value of i is pushed on a stack. Then, the variable i is incremented. Finally, the value on top the stack is popped off and assigned into i. The net result is that nothing happens -- `a smart optimizer could remove the whole statement.`